# Will increasing spawn area increase guardian spawns? [1.11.2]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've been building [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=200P9dnsyJo) Guardian farm on a Multiplayer server.
I cleared out all the water and removed the temple itself.

Then, I built the glass box in the middle and filled it with water. 
Guardians do spawn a bit, but I want to higher the rates if possible.

And yes, I have lit up all nearby caves.

So I was wondering: will making the box bigger affect/improve my spawn rates? 
Or does every temple have a set amount of spawns that will be concentrated if the spawning area is smaller than the temple monument.

Thanks.

**Screenshots**

[image: Guardian Farm]
[image: Guardian Farm]
[image: Guardian Farm]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Increasing spawn area will increase spawns.**

If you increase the spawn area, spawn checks that would normally fail will now succeed, but at a certain point, there will be so many guardians spawning at a time that more will be unable to spawn.

Comment: Okay, thanks.

Just out of curiosity; what sources do you have?

Comment: It was a video by Xisumavoid, don't remember the exact one, but I remember that in general, if you have a larger spawn area, more spawn tries will be successful, up to a point.

Answer (score -1):

It wil have more than double the spawnrate if you put a roon on it. No direct sunlight is the key.